# How to configure Cruise Control .NET to see modifications in one svn folder and checkout different folder

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have the following folder structure under snv:

```
trunk
     /project1
     /project2
     /shared
     /libs
```

I want to configure CruiseControl.Net to check project folder (`https://server/.../trunk/project1`) for modifications and checkout the whole trunk (`https://server/.../trunk`).

How can I do it in CruiseControl.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Filtered Source Control Block](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered) to enclose your subversion source control provider. It allows you to trigger only on certain changes, while still checking out the whole sub-tree.